# Why XML max entity size is limited by bug fix

Tags: java

In Java 8 Update 71 (8u71) default limit added for XML maximum entity size as a bug fix. But why this limit had been a bug, what is the issue with that and if we are changing this limit what is the maximum size allowable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u71-relnotes-2773756.html), you'd find a reference to [The Java Tutorials, Processing Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/index.html) that explains it:

> XML processing can sometimes be a memory intensive operation. Applications, especially those that accept XML, XSD and XSL from untrusted sources, should take steps to guard against excessive memory consumption by using the JAXP processing limits provided in the JDK.

Without a limit, a malicious XML can crash your application.

According to [The Java Tutorials, Processing Limit Definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/limits/limits.html), there is a `totalEntitySizeLimit` of `50,000,000`, and a `maxParameterEntitySizeLimit` of `1,000,000`.

Remember, these are *entities*, which are very rarely used these days, so it doesn't really affect most people.